# How to pass JSF InputText value to ajax listener

Tags: java, jsf

I want to pass value in the input box to the ajax listener. Please refer following code.

JSF :

```xml
<h:dataTable id="cleanerAttendance" value="#{bean.objMap.entrySet().toArray()}">
    <h:column> 
        <f:facet name="header">
            <div>Attendance</div>
        </f:facet>
        <div>
            <h:inputText value="entry.value">
                <f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{bean.updateMap(entry)}"/>
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Bean :

```
private Map<Obj2,Integer> objMap = new HashMap<Obj2,Integer>();

public void updateMap(Entry<Obj2,Integer> entry){
    System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    objMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

I want to update objMap when input value changed. But when I run this, updateMap method get called. But `entry.getValue()` print as `null`. Does anyone know why it is not working and correct way to do this?

I have already checked following answers and it was not worked for me.

[Pass h:inputText value to f:ajax listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988432/pass-hinputtext-value-to-fajax-listener?rq=1)

[How to pass parameter to f:ajax in h:inputText? f:param does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396244/how-to-pass-parameter-to-fajax-in-hinputtext-fparam-does-not-work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameter to f:ajax in h:inputText? f:param does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396244/how-to-pass-parameter-to-fajax-in-hinputtext-fparam-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it other way. First provide a getter for the Map:

```
public Map<Obj2,Integer> getObjMap(){
  return objMap;
}
```

Then iterate over the keys and set the value based in the key you're interested in:

```xml
<h:dataTable id="cleanerAttendance" value="#{bean.objMap.keySet().toArray()}" var="obj">
    <h:column> 
        <f:facet name="header">
            <div>Attendance</div>
        </f:facet>
        <div>
            <h:inputText value="#{bean.objMap[obj]}">
                <f:ajax execute="@this" />
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

This will basically invoke the model update once each of the ajax binded event happens, no listener needed. Haven't tested it myself, so give it a try!

**See also:**

- [How to set a Map value in h:inputText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977578/how-to-set-a-map-value-in-hinputtext)

Comment: is it possible with JSF 2.1? (iterate over Set)

Comment: No, only starting from 2.2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7712593/1199132 You might still fallback to `.toArray()`.